# sqlite and mysql. which is better when the applications has all processes running on the same machine and when the database has hardly 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I need to choose between SQLite and MYSql. I am a little confused on what to choose. I know that both database engines have no recursive query mechanisms and SQLite doesn't support stored procedures. 
This is my situation.
I have an application which has around 1000 processes accessing the same database. The database has around 2 tables and around 10,000 entries in total. The application isn't distributed, I mean all processes are running on the same machine. I want to embed the database in the application itself. I think MYSql isn't a good idea keeping all these in mind.
Also my application doesn't involve complex queries (a couple of select, update and insert queries)
I know that SQLite is much lighter than MYSql but MYSql supports stored procedures and SQLite doesn't. I also need good locking mechanisms. I don't want a process to lock the table for a long time. I've read that locking/unlocking operations are pretty fast in SQLite (http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html). I am new to Databases, please bear with me. Could anyone please help me deciding what is better.

Comment: How can you have "hardly" or "around" 2 tables? This is a pretty precise number

Comment: If you want to embed a relational database in Java you might also want to consider HSQLDB or H2

Comment: 1000 separate processes on a single machine?  That is a large number, even for a monster server.  If you think that you might need, when this application is running at scale, to switch over to running some of these processes on second or third machines, you'll need mySQL.  But mySQL is going to have a hard time with 1000 simultaneous connections. You may wish to spend more time designing this application before specifying your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

for embedding a small database into an app, SQLite is the best way to go - mySQL would be more useful for a database on a server. Localized app data +SQLite = easier to develop and implement